# Navegation case y JSF no muestran nada

Tags: java, xml, jsf, xhtml

llevo dias con este problema, donde hago toda la estructura de navegacion entre pantallas pero no me devuelve nada y solo un boton que es el del index es el unico que me funciona, intente solucionarlo poniendole ajax="false" y al principio me funciono pero nos e que sucedio que ahora ya no me muestra nada, podrian ayudarme se los agradeceria.

aqui les dejo el codigo del mangedbean, el de la barra de navegacion que no quiere mostra y el Face Config

codigo ManagedBean

```js
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package cr.go.rnp.siansa;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

/**
 *
 * @author JulioColHdz
 */
@ManagedBean//(name = "buttonView")
@SessionScoped
public class ButtonView {

    public String buttonExit() {
        return "exit";
    }
    public void messageView(){
        addMessage("Se agregó correctamente!!");
    }
     
    public String buttonAction() {
        addMessage("Bienvenido a SIANSA!!");
        return "success";
    }
    
    public String segmentoEstilos(){
        return "segmento";
    }
    
    public String registroUsuarios(){
        return "usuario"; 
    }
    
    public void addMessage(String summary) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, summary, null);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }       
}
```

Codigo del Face Config

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2"
              xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
    
    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
       
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>segmento</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/TablaEstilos.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
        
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>Home.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
        
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>exit</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>index.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
         
         <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>usuario</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>RegistroUsuarios.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
         
    </navigation-rule>     
</faces-config>
```

codigo barra

```html
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<!-- Barra de Navegacion   -->
    <h:form>
        <p:menubar  style="background: #333; color: #fff; width: 1185px; height: 30px;">
            <p:menuitem>
                <h:graphicImage value="/imgs/Slidenew1.png" style="margin-left: 10px; " width="50px" height="70px"></h:graphicImage>
            </p:menuitem>
            <p:submenu label="SIANSA" icon="ui-icon-person" style="width: 110px; color: #fff;">
                <p:menuitem value="Perfil" url="#" icon="ui-icon-person" style="color: black;"></p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem value="Registro de Usuarios" action="#{buttonView.registroUsuarios}" icon="ui-icon-plusthick" style="color: black;" ajax="false"></p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem value="Salir" action="#{buttonView.buttonExit}" style="color: black;" icon="ui-icon-closethick" ajax="false"></p:menuitem>
            </p:submenu>          
            <p:menuitem value="Segmento Estilos" action="#{buttonView.segmentoEstilos}" style="color: white;" ajax="false"></p:menuitem>
            <p:menuitem value="Segmento Clases" style="color: white;"></p:menuitem>
            <p:submenu label="Consultas" icon="ui-icon-help" style="width: 125px; color: #CCCCCC;">
                <p:menuitem value="General" url="#" style="color: black;"></p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem value="Por Estilos" url="#" style="color: black;"></p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem value="Por Clases" url="#" style="color: black;"></p:menuitem>
            </p:submenu>
            <p:menuitem value="Home" action="#{buttonView.buttonAction}" icon="ui-icon-home" style="color: whitesmoke; float: right;" ajax="false" ></p:menuitem>
        </p:menubar> 
    </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: La pregunta no es clara, dónde va el composition ? Normalmente con ajax se recomienda  ViewScoped